# font similar to Fight-this with polish characters

Tags: typography, font-identification, web-fonts

I'm looking for a font similar to [Fight-this](http://www.decalfont.com/it/fight-this.font) with Polish characters (Latin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the history of this font, it's tied to the 1999 movie "Fight Club":

[image: Fight Club movie poster]

The font says that version 2.0 was released by [Apostrophic Labs](http://moorstation.org/typoasis/designers/lab/) in 2000 and according to [this source of unknown repute](http://fontmeme.com/fight-club-font/) it was first released in 1999.

So, it's reasonable to say that there's probably no version of this with Polish characters around. Here are a few options:

- Embedded in the font file (at least the one that is available from the moorstation.org link I included) is a copyright notice that includes an e-mail address. You can e-mail them and ask!
- You could theoretically modify the font yourself using a free tool like [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/). Not for the faint of heart and this might create legal issues, though.
- Use an alternate, like you asked. [League Gothic](https://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/league-gothic) comes to mind because it has regular and narrow oblique variants:

[image: League Gothic demonstration]

Another option would be something like [DIN Condensed Italic](http://www.fontshop.com/fonts/singles/fontfont/ff_din_ot_condensed_bold_italic/opentype_cff/):

[image: DIN Demonstration]

Basically, any sturdy sans-serif where you can get a "Condensed Bold Italic" variant. Experiment and see what works. The stuff like the modified "B", "G", "R", and "D" you can probably do pretty easily in Illustrator.

Comment: I knew history of font, just was looking for something similar I'll probably use League Gothic  as you sugessted. Thanks.